# What are good tools for identifying potentially duplicated code for C# Express users?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-express

see also "[Any tools to check for duplicate VB.NET code?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266978/any-tools-to-check-for-duplicate-vb-net-code)

A friend of mine only has access to the Express editions of Visual Studio and I am trying to help him refactor to remove a lot of duplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a look at [Simian](http://www.harukizaemon.com/simian/) or [DuplicateFinder](http://duplicatefinder.codeplex.com/). Neither have a dependency on the IDE, although you can [integrate](http://blogs.conchango.com/howardvanrooijen/archive/2006/02/08/2776.aspx) Simian [quite easily](http://blogs.conchango.com/howardvanrooijen/archive/2006/02/18/2888.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

[Clone Detective](http://clonedetectivevs.codeplex.com/) appears as though it might work for you. I haven't used it before, but I stumbled across it on codeplex this week.

Comment: I've used it once or twice before but it did report some false positives, not many though.

Comment: Looking at the page, this states VS Standard or higher. It won't work with Express.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend should take a look at [Gendarme](http://www.mono-project.com/Gendarme), a FOSS and cross-platform alternative to Microsoft's FxCop/Code Analysis which is part of the Mono project. It [includes](http://www.mono-project.com/Gendarme.Rules.Smells#AvoidCodeDuplicatedInSameClassRule) [rules](http://www.mono-project.com/Gendarme.Rules.Smells#AvoidCodeDuplicatedInSiblingClassesRule) that check for duplicated code.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Atomiq](http://www.getatomiq.com/):

> Atomiq Code Similarity Finder is a tool for developers to find and eliminate duplicate code. It is designed for .NET developers, but works equally well for developers of other languages and even web designers!
>   Atomiq works with a wide variety of source code:
>
> We currently support C#, VB.Net, ASPX, Ruby, Python, Java, C, C++,
>   ActionScript, and XAML, with more extensions on the way soon. It is
>   the perfect companion tool for someone who updates their code
>   infrequently and can't possibly remember everything in it or for a
>   team of 2 or more developers working on the same project that don't
>   know everything in it since they didn't write it all themselves.
>
> Eliminate similar code
>
> (and the banging your head against the wall that comes with it) Atomiq
>   doesn't just find exact matches, it finds similar code. It ignores
>   "fluff" like whitespace, string content, curly braces, comments and
>   using/import statements so you can find the duplicate code that causes
>   problems. In VB.NET, it will also ignore lines that contain only
>   "Next", "End While", "End Try", "End If", "End Property", "End Get"
>   and "End Set".

Comment: The download link for this one seems broken, I get a 404 error on their dropbox link

Answer (score 0):

More as fyi, since you mentioned 'express edition' you might need to look for something that would work outside of VS, since I don't believe the express editions support plugins

Comment: The express editions explicitly don't support plug-ins. Technically it does, as some of the features shipped by MS are plug-ins, but hoops are jumped to make them work.

Answer (score 0):

See our [CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone), which operates on many langauges, including C#.

EDIT October 2010:  VB6, VBScript and VB.net added as languages supported by CloneDR.
There is no specific support for MS IDEs, but it operates on a simple list of source files, and produces a nice HTML report, so not much integration is needed.  See sample reports at link.