# Anyone used ConQAT with a VB.NET code base

Tags: vb.net

To quote from the [ConQAT - Continuous Quality Assessment Toolkit](http://conqat.cs.tum.edu/index.php/ConQAT) website

> Long-lived software systems are
>   subject to gradual quality decay if no
>   counter measures are taken. Continuous
>   quality control counters this decay
>   through an orchestrated application of
>   constructive and analytic quality
>   assurance techniques. The Continuous
>   Quality Assessment Toolkit ConQAT
>   provides the tool-support required to
>   enact continuous quality control in
>   practice. It supports the rapid
>   development of quality dashboards that
>   integrate diverse quality analysis
>   methods and tools.

However before I spend lots of time looking at it, is it usefull for a VB.NET project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes. Many of the analyses of ConQAT can be applied to multiple languages. Its two most widely used analyses, namely clone detection and architecture analysis, can be performed for VB.NET.

We are currently working on the ConQAT 2.6 release. I will try to include VB.NET analyses in the ConQAT Examples. Let me know if you are interested to try it before the next release. I can provide configurations that work for VB.NET.

Best regards,
Elmar

P.S.: I am one of the maintainers of ConQAT.